# ListView and GridView gets cleared between tab switches

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-listview, fragment

I have an activity with 3 tabs. Each time I switch between tabs, my ListView and GridView (on first tab) gets cleared, interestingly the ArrayList contains all the data downloaded earlier and if I call my addToGrid() function, the ListView is populated nicely.

Why gets List and Grid views cleared while switching between tabs. Are the containing fragments recreated on each tab switch? Do I need to query my database and repopulate my views between each tab switch?

Thanks!

BY THE WAY - I have added an "if"-statement in the onResume function. If I leave the "if" statement the listview doubles the rows, and repopulates it again and again when switching back. But with the "if" statement on, my listviews stay empty onResume because as I have mentioned the ArrayList still has all the data.

excerpt from the fragment containing the ListView:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offers_view, null, false);                                    

            SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("USERINFO", 
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            user = preferences.getString("name", null);


            Button showAllUserImages = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.showAllUserImages);
            showAllUserImages.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
                @Override
                  public void onClick(View v)  {                    
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AllUserImages.class);
                    startActivity(i);                      
                }                
               }); 

            RelativeLayout topLoc = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.topLocationsBtn);
            topLoc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
                @Override
                  public void onClick(View v)  {                    
                       Intent loc = new Intent(getActivity(), com.fideli.top.guide.TopLocations.class);
                       startActivity(loc);                         
                    }                
               }); 

            RelativeLayout guide = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.guideBtn);
            guide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
                @Override
                  public void onClick(View v)  {                    
                       Intent i= new Intent(getActivity(), com.fideli.top.guide.GloveGuide.class);
                       startActivity(i);                       
                    }                
               }); 



          return v;          
    }



    @Override
    public void onPause() {     
        super.onPause();
        System.out.println("paused!");


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {        
        super.onResume();

        if(imageItems.isEmpty()){
        getInfoFromDB();

        }

        if(tasteMakersList.isEmpty()){
        getTastemakers();
        }

        if(feedList.isEmpty()){
        downloadFeed();
        }

    }



   private void downloadFeed() {

       AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();      
        System.out.println("Downloading Feed!!");
        client.get("http://www.edmondvarga.com/android_dev/fideli/get-relations.php?mainUser=" + user, null, 
                                    new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {             
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                try {                                       
                    JSONArray contacts = response.getJSONArray("info");

                    for (int i=0; i< contacts.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json = contacts.getJSONObject(i);                            

                        String followedUser = json.getString("folwed_users");                       
                        getFeed(followedUser);

                    }                   
                } catch (JSONException e) {                 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
            }  

         });


    }



    public void getInfoFromDB(){

        datasource = new SQLiteDataSource(getActivity());
        datasource.open();


        List<ImageItem> values = datasource.getAllImageItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {

            ImageItem ii = new ImageItem(null, null);

            ii.setImage(values.get(i).getImage());
            ii.setUser(values.get(i).getUser());
            ii.setUserId(values.get(i).getUserId());
            ii.setLikes(values.get(i).getLikes());
            ii.setDescription(values.get(i).getDescription());
            ii.setLocation(values.get(i).getLocation());    
            ii.setAddress(values.get(i).getAddress());
            ii.setCity(values.get(i).getCity());
            ii.setLat(values.get(i).getLat());
            ii.setLng(values.get(i).getLng());          


            imageItems.add(ii);
            addToGrid();
        }

    }

            public void addToGrid() {
                gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
                customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_grid, imageItems);          
                gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);         
                gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view is most likely getting destroyed but the fragment probably isn't. I know this happens in a `ViewPager` when the user has navigated more than one page away. So if your `imageItems` variable is an instance variable, it isn't recreated since the fragment is still created.  See the lifecycle diagram in the [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) guide.